# How to get capacity specifications for a particular Oracle release?

Tags: oracle, database-design

How to get capacity specifications for new Oracle release(Oracle 11.2.0.4)?
ie, information like

How much schema we can create?,

How much tables a schema can accommodate?

How much rows total instance can have?

How can I get these information? Or from where I can get these information?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The answer to all of that is essentially: "unlimited". I would start looking in the Concepts guide, most probably it's documented there. Note that in Oracle you usually don't create more than one "database". A "database" in Oracle is something **completely** different than a "database" in Postgres, SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: by databases I meant schema....Will edit the question

Comment: The answer will still be (is) ...Essentially "unlimited"

Answer (score 1):

[Physical Database Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/limits002.htm#REFRN0042)

[Logical Database Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/limits003.htm#REFRN0043)

The maximum number of users (schemas): 2^31 = 2147483648

The official answer to your other questions: unlimited.

The practical answer is: as many as your hardware/operating system/design can handle.